# JavaScript - Keep date value in non-complete field

Tags: javascript

I've looked everywhere with no result.

I'm working on a little form that allows users to subscribe themselves on a site.
There is a table with some cells and textnodes including also a 'date' field.

With 'onfocus' event cells are colored in blue during editing.
With 'onblur' event cells recover previous color, except if they include wrong value (e.g. numbers in 'name' field): in this case cells become red.

I've some problem with 'date' field.

I give example: user start to write birthday date and for some reason doesn't complete the field before change cell....or user after complete date field press ESC.
I both cases, if I try to read field value using getelementbyId().value, it returns '' (empty).

Is there any way to read value in these cases?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: Create a [mcve].

Answer (score 0):

According to the specification([WHATWG](https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/input.html#date-state-(type=date))) you cann't access this value.

> The value sanitization algorithm is as follows: If the value of the element is not a valid date string, then set it to the empty string instead.

Same for [W3](https://www.w3.org/TR/html52/sec-forms.html#date-state-typedate)

> User agents must not allow the user to set the value to a non-empty string that is not a valid date string.